# Could a rotorcraft fly on Triton?

Tags: atmosphere, uncrewed-spaceflight, triton

*Mars 2020* will use a drone to fly within Mars' atmosphere. Although it's thin, Mars also has a lower surface gravity which makes airflight possible on Mars. What about Neptune's moon Triton? Triton has an even thinner atmosphere than Mars but also a much weaker gravity of 0.78 m/s² or 0.08 g. Voyager 2 reportedly observed clouds on Triton, so if clouds can fly there, perhaps a rotorcraft would be able too. There's a proposed lander for Triton, the *Triton Hopper*, but it is to use its engine to fly on Triton, not some propellers. Would it be feasible to fly a rotorcraft there?

Comment: For those like me who skip the middle of words while reading and got half way into an answer, this question is about Triton, moon of Neptune, not Titan, moon of Saturn and candidate for the dragonfly mission https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragonfly_(spacecraft)

Comment: Related <strike>XKCD</strike> [What-If](https://what-if.xkcd.com/30/)…

Comment: @GremlinWranger Titan (Saturn), Titania (Uranus) and Triton (Neptune) are not to be confused. Dragonfly actually IS a rotorcraft. Titan's atmosphere is denser than the Earth's.

Comment: Oddly enough, you might find more experts at the   aircraft SE site.  My suspicion is there's some nice formula about   Can_I_Fly = f(weight, lift)  , and lift =  g(attack_angle, wing_speed, atmos_density).    For you, weight depends on local gravity, and the only other variable that changes is the atmospheric density

Comment: One issue is keeping it warm, it will likely need some RTG or something to keep it warm and to generate power for locomotion. Perhaps if there was a lander with the main (heavy) RTG and a battery powered flyer, it could return to it before it's batteries ran out each time.